# How to implement SUM with @QuerySqlFunction?

Tags: gridgain, ignite

The examples seen so far that cover **@QuerySqlFunction** are trivial. I put one below. However, I'm looking for an example / solution / hint for providing a cross row calculation, e.g. average, sum, ... Is this possible?

In the example, the function returns value 0 from an array, basically an implementation of ARRAY_GET(x, 0). All other examples I've seen are similar: 1 row, get a value, do something with it. But I need to be able to calculate the sum of a grouped result, or possible a lot more business logic. If somebody could provide me with the QuerySqlFunction for SUM, I assume would allow me to do much more than just SUM.

**Step 1: Write a function**

```
public class MyIgniteFunctions {
@QuerySqlFunction
public static double value1(double[] values) {
    return values[0];
}
}
```

**Step 2: Register the function**

```
CacheConfiguration<Long, MyFact> factResultCacheCfg = ...
factResultCacheCfg.setSqlFunctionClasses(new Class[] { MyIgniteFunctions.class });
```

**Step 3: Use it in a query**

```
SELECT
      MyDimension.groupBy1,
      MyDimension.groupBy2,
      SUM(VALUE1(MyFact.values))
FROM
     "dimensionCacheName".DimDimension,  
     "factCacheName".FactResult
WHERE
      MyDimension.uid=MyFact.dimensionUid
GROUP BY  
      MyDimension.groupBy1,
      MyDimension.groupBy2
```

Comment: Ignite does support standard sql SUM function. Will it be enough for you? Or you want to implement some custom aggregate function?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of another question and was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097103/how-to-sum-an-array-of-doubles-with-ignite-data-grid-sql

Comment: I know and understand there's the standard sql SUM function available. I don't need a SUM. What I need is an example implementation of QuerySqlFunction that provides functionality across multiple rows. Having an implementation of SUM as an QuerySqlFunction would be a good example. This would allow me to understand how to write a QuerySqlFunction across multiple rows, given a specific context, e.g. a "group by".

Comment: The other question refered to by @Dmitriy isn't a duplicate. The other question is on how to sum the elements of an array, element by element, using SQL, or any other means.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Ignite currently has clean API support for custom user-defined QuerySqlFunction that spans multiple rows.

If you need something like this, I would suggest that you make use of [IgniteCompute APIs](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid) and distribute your computations, lambdas, or closures to the participating Ignite nodes. Then from inside of your closure, you can either execute local SQL queries, or perform any other cache operations, including predicate-based scans over locally cached data.

This approach will be executed across multiple Ignite nodes in parallel and should perform well.